# Access Rails global constant in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2, jQuery 1.6.2

Rails

```
constants.rb (initializer file)

DEFAULT_REPLY = "Add a reply..."
```

Rails

```
index.html.erb 

<%= javascript_include_tag 'reply' %>
...(rest of view code)...

reply.js

$(function() {
 var default_reply = <%= h DEFAULT_REPLY -%>;
 ...(rest of jQuery code)...
});
```

This throws an error `Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected token %=`, I tried to enclose it in quotes like `var default_reply = '<%= h DEFAULT_REPLY -%>'` and it output the value as is, meaning `default_value` has the value of `<%= h DEFAULT_REPLY -%>'` which is clearly not what I intended. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Given the feedback, I have reconsidered and is now using a local variable and jQuery to pull the value from the textarea upon page load.

Comment: Global constant just for text message?

Comment: No, not just for that. The global constant is also used in a couple of the views (in multiple places) that I didn't state in my question. I didn't want to over-complicate my question. Do you mind removing your down vote?

Comment: Does "var default_reply = <%= 'test' -%>;" throw the same error? Also, is the error thrown by rails or in the javascript?

Comment: @spike, it throws the same JS error

Answer (score 2):

You need to add .erb to the end of your .js file, along with add the quotes around the string.

The name of your javascript file should be reply.js.erb.

Currently, your .js file is not being run through rails, and is being served statically. That is why when you put the quotes around the string, it output the string '<%= h DEFAULT_REPLY %>' instead of the correct text.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, your answer is the first one that made sense to me though I have since abandoned the use of a global constant.

Answer (score 2):

**I'd strongly recommend against this approach** but I think you're confusing two things here.

Assuming `reply.js` is in `public/javascripts/reply.js`, this is a static JS file that is served up by your server. You cannot put any dynamic ("server side") code in here as the file is not evaluated in any manner, just passed back statically.

If you want a global JS variable to use in your files, you'd need to do assign it in your `layout` file `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` or in your action files (`index.html.erb`, `show.html.erb`, etc).

Any `ERB` file is evaluated before returning it, so you could put

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
   var default_reply = "<%= escape_javascript DEFAULT_REPLY %>";
  });
</script>
```

above the `<%= yield %>` statement of your `layout` file.

Again, I'd **STRONGLY** recommend against this approach but if that's why you need, I think this will solve it.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess it's not good practice. I am now using a local variable and jQuery to pull the value from the textarea upon page load.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you named your view template incorrectly, does it end in .html.erb?  If not, it won't evaluate the ERB fragment you pasted.

Once you fix that, you can embed what you want with the following ERB code:

```
$(function() {
 var default_reply = "<%= h DEFAULT_REPLY -%>";
 ...
});
```

Comment: Hmm, the global constant is not in a view template obviously, let me try that and see how it works.

Comment: I'm asking you what the filename of the template is you pasted this code fragment from (the jQuery block).

Comment: Oh, the filename is `index.html.erb` which includes the jQuery JS file, so it's the proper setup but I still have the issue as described above.

Comment: You may need to post the entire template then to find why you've got a syntax error.

Comment: That's too much code to post and not particularly understandable out-of-context. What I can say is that the rest of the code works perfectly fine until I added that one line of code which throws the error.

Comment: If it a rails 3 App  why that syntax?
try:  `var default_reply = "<%= DEFAULT_REPLY %>";`

Answer (score -2):

If it is a rails 3 App why are you using that syntax? try:

`var default_reply = <%= DEFAULT_REPLY %>;`

Comment: nop , see yours : `var default_reply = <%= h DEFAULT_REPLY -%>`

Comment: Look, with or without `-` and / or `h`, it threw the same error. Look at the other comments why it is so.

Comment: but that is the old sintax of erb used in rails 2.x. 
In all cases the problem is other